# Column title is changed when saved to csv format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a column in a dataframe (*df*) in pandas called *"9-7"*. When I use `df.to_csv('df.csv')` to save the dataframe, the title of the column is changed to *7-Sep*. It means the date of the 7 of September. However, I need the title of *"9-7"*.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it is tested in excel? If use some text editer like notepad++ same problem?

Comment: the problem with excel, but no issue with notepad++

Comment: Yes, excel sometimes change formats :) So all working nice, pandas wokring here perfectly :)

Comment: If you want to continue in excel you could use the `to_excel()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with excel's interpretation of data. A csv-file is nothing more than a table in string format.

If you are going to continue in excel you could use `to.excel()` function:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'9-7':[1]}).to_csv('test.csv',index=False)     # This will not work
pd.DataFrame({'9-7':[1]}).to_excel('test.xlsx',index=False)  # This will
```